# How to get the cluster node IPs using Pulumi

Tags: javascript, digital-ocean, pulumi

Here is an example of creating a managed Kubernetes cluster on DigitalOcean.

```js
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as digitalocean from "@pulumi/digitalocean";

const foo = new digitalocean.KubernetesCluster("foo", {
    region: "nyc1",
    version: "1.20.2-do.0",
    nodePool: {
        name: "front-end-pool",
        size: "s-2vcpu-2gb",
        nodeCount: 3,
    },
});
```

Example code taken from the [Pulumi DigitalOcean package documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/digitalocean/api-docs/kubernetesnodepool/).

How do I retrieve the droplet node IPv4 addresses for use in say creating `DnsRecord` resources?

```js
const _default = new digitalocean.Domain("default", {name: "example.com"});

// This code doesn't work because foo.nodePool is just the inputs.
const dnsRecords = foo.nodePool.nodes(node => new digitalocean.DnsRecord("www", {
    domain: _default.name,
    type: "A",
    value: node.ipv4Address,
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DigitalOcean doesn't return a list of node IP addresses from the Kubernetes cluster you created. You can retrieve these values using the `getDroplet` function.

However, you'll need to do this iteration inside an `apply()` like so:

```js
const addresses = foo.nodePool.nodes.apply(
    nodes => nodes.forEach(
        (node) => {
            let n = digitalocean.getDropletOutput({
                name: node.name
            })
            new digitalocean.DnsRecord("www", {
                domain: domain.name,
                type: "A",
                value: n.ipv4Address,
            })
        }
    )
)
```

Using an apply here lets us wait until the `foo.nodePool.nodes` has been created by the API. We can then iterate over it like a normal array, get the droplet, assign it to the variable `n` and then create a new DNS record for each of the nodes

Comment: `getDropletOutput` returns a promse doesn't it need awaiting?

Comment: not if you're passing the result to another resource, no.